# After merge css and js files are turned on, the files remain not contiguous

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css, merge-css

After turning on merge of css and js files in `System > Configuration > Developer` and clearing the cache, files are not merged

The request numbers do not change
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try this with SSH once. You can please execute below commands:

```
php bin/magento config:set dev/js/merge_files 1
php bin/magento config:set dev/css/merge_css_files 1
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

I have already used these commands in many projects. This should be working fine for you as well.

Let me know if you have any more queries.

Thanks,